# Data Table Classes in UML Sequence Diagrams

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I've been struggling to understand the transition from a **UML Class Design Diagram** to a **UML Sequence Diagram** for a school assignment. My design class diagram contains a central **DataManager** class that connects the **use case control classes** to the **data table classes** (ie. user, product, employee), however, do I need to include the data table classes in my use cases' sequence diagrams?

[Design Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lbxI.png)

[My Sequence Diagram Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4x6l.png)

Comment: Please be more specific and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: And so a point is: a model is always a partial view of the whole system, and a model has to have a goal, an objective. Depending of your objective, you have to show data table classes (strange name anyway) or you do not have to show them. So what is your concern when you model this sequence ?

Comment: From a process point of view, a proper use case should have given you enough information to create both sequences of events (which are easy to translate to sequence diagrams) and a set of classes (e.g., data/model, interface/view, and behavior/controller) expressing your domain model (as a class diagram).  You should then be able to map the domain model element onto the sequence diagram.
@granier: a model _can_ be a view of  complete system, a diagram should _never_ be a complete view of a system, unless the system is trivial, in which case, why model?

Comment: @ChalresRivet, you're right i mixed models and schemas, anyway the way you translate UC in sequences depends of the goal of the schema.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I guess what I really meant is whether the communication between the DataManager class and the tables should be included in the sequence diagram. I found a few examples from previous labs where they did include the interaction between these two with a message signature of `sql()`, since the tables are stored in an SQL database system.

Comment: But of course you can include messages to read data from DB, and you can write the message which is a method call: the "exact" method call. You sequences diagram is confusing: you do not uses classes of the class schema.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end, I didn't phrase my question as I wanted to. I was asking if communications between the database tables and the data manager class should also appear in the sequence diagram. The answer is, **they should**. The whole point of having a sequence diagram is to guide a developer in the "development" of a class. For my diagrams, all messages I used for this communication had a standard `sql()` operation for each message.